# Symfony2 Users getting logged as other users because of cache

Tags: symfony, varnish

The worst scenario happened.

Although i took all the necessary precautions, it seems that varnish cached a page where a user was logged in.

**Now, when you go on my website, you are connected as this XXX person which is obviously not you. And you can edit his profile...**

**I cached 2 pages only** (homepage, and one listing page) on which I have the tag :

```
@Cache(smaxage="10800")
```

And in ALL my templates, I used ESI (for menu/footer/login modale) in order to prevent those kind of situation :

```
{% render "HomeBundle:Home:login" with { 'appRequestUri' : app.request.uri }, { 'standalone': true } %}
{% render 'HomeBundle:Home:menu' with { 'locale' : app.request.locale }, { 'standalone': true } %}
```

The Login action does not have a `@Cache` annotation.

Here my [default.vcl](http://pastie.org/private/ehjfeg2pxvtynhacsgjzw) used by Varnish.

What am I doing wrong please ?

PS: I do have `esi: { enabled: true }` and imported the esi routes in `routing.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your VCL, it appears you will cache each requests with a **Cookie** inside. It's not really what you wanted, isn't ?

I suggest you to close your **vcl_recv** as sooner as you can  :

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        return (pass);
    }
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";
 }
```

Doing this way, the default **vcl_recv** will be called just after and all your logged requests will not be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's because of the cache.
You wouldn't be able to edit the profile if it was just the cache, because you would get the users's cached page but not his session...

Comment: I don't see how it's possible : It only happens when varnish is activated. You are connected as another user without doing any login process (it's not like doctrine fetching the wrong user).